# How can I prove that a bank owes me money

Tags: banking, bank-account

How am I, as a customer of a bank able to prove that I have a deposit-account with money on it?

For example what would happen if the computer-system has a bug in it that affects my account. Bank says I owe 5 euro, while in fact I owe 10 euro.

I was wondering are there any safety messuraces in place to avoid this kind of situations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical disaster scenario.

Comment: Banks are generally required to safeguard their data and keep proper backups. They're also required to provide you periodic statements which you should inspect for errors and save. Hypothetical questions are generally off-topic. Do you have any specific issue with any specific bank that you're trying to resolve?

Answer (score 3):

If you open an account, you sign a contract, of which you get a copy. That ultimately proves that the account exists.

As for the money in an account: [Double-entry accounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system) makes it more or less impossible for that to be simply wrong. An account balance is not just a number; it's a sum of transactions, each of which has a corresponding entry in another account where the money came from or went to.

What is possible (but extremely rare given the effort banks go to in order to ensure the correctness of their systems) is for transactions to get lost or stuck (because they often have multiple stages), or to have a wrong source or target, or amount.

If a transaction gets lost, it's the same as if it never happened - the money is still in the sender's account and you have to convince them to send it to you.

If a transaction got stuck, i.e. money was sent but did not arrive, the sender can request their bank to investigate what happened and fix the problem. If an erroneous transaction shows up on your account, you can do the same. Double-entry accounting ensures that this is always possible.